# Loop over files in subdir and put output in other subdir

Tags: python

I want to perform an action on all files in a subdir and put the out put in another dir. For example, in /Pictures/ there are subdirs /January, /February/ etc and in them imgages. I want to perform actions on the images and put the output to /Processed/ and its subdirs /January, /Februady etc.

I imagine it to be solved something like this, but I really could use some help:

```
import os
path = '/Pictures/'
outpath = '/Processed/'
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    #do something with files and send out put to corresponding output dir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the basic structure :

```
import os
path = 'Pictures/' # NOTE: Without starting '/' !
outpath = 'Processed/'
for old_dir, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
    new_dir = old_dir.replace(path, outpath, 1)
    if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
        print "Creating %s" % new_dir
        os.makedirs(new_dir)
    for filename in filenames:
        old_path = os.path.join(old_dir, filename)
        new_path = os.path.join(new_dir, filename)
        print "Processing : %s -> %s" % (old_path, new_path)
        # do something with new_path
```

It creates the same subfolder structure in `'Processed/'` as in `'Pictures/'` and it iterates over every filename.

For every file in your folders, you get the `new_path` variable :

`old_path` is `'Pictures/1/test.jpg'`, `new_path` will be `'Processed/1/test.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

This basically walks through all folders of a directory, gets its files; perform some action with `performFunction()` and write to the same file. **You can modify this to write to different path!**

```
def walkDirectory(directory, filePattern):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory),followlinks=True):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
         try:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(filepath) as f:
                s = f.read()
            s = performFunction()

            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                print filepath
                f.write(s)
                f.flush()
            f.close()
         except:
           import traceback
           print traceback.format_exc()
```

Hope it helps!